# Click on image to change chosen plugin item

Tags: javascript, joomla, jquery-chosen

I'm working on a layout for a product using hikashop in joomla. example page can be seen here: [*product page*](http://zink.development.webdesign-toledo.com/zink/duck-calls/ph-1-custom-single#). The characteristics select box is using the Chosen plugin. What I am trying to accomplish is to have the thumbnail images below change the selected item in the select box like this:

```
<img id="hikashop_product_characteristic_35"     
    onclick="document.getElementById('hikashop_product_characteristic_19').value='35';"  
    class="hikashop_child_image" 
    src="/zink/media/com_hikashop/upload/nbg_blackstealth_1061075554.png" 
    alt="hikashop_child_image_35">
```

Well if this was working, clearly I wouldn't be posing here. I think the chosen plugin overrides the select box, and i dont know enough about this to work around, so any help would be appreciated.

@isherwood - I tried your example and am getting UncaughtSyntaxError: Unexpected Token ;
Not too sure where my error is, here is my entire code block:

```
foreach($this->element->variants as $variant){
                foreach($variant->characteristics as $k => $characteristic){
                    $char_id = $characteristic->variant_characteristic_id;
                    $cat_id = $k;
                }
                foreach($variant->images as $image){
                    echo '
                        <img id="hikashop_product_characteristic_'.$char_id.'" class="hikashop_child_image" src="' . $this->image->uploadFolder_url . $image->file_path . '" alt="hikashop_child_image_' . $char_id . '"  />'; ?>
                        <script>
                            char_id = '<?php echo $char_id ?>'
                        </script>
            <?php
                }
            } ?>
            <script>
                $('img.hikashop_child_image').click(function() {
                    $('#hikashop_product_characteristic_19').val(char_id);
                }
            </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

After you set your select value, you need to update Chosen:

```
$("#hikashop_product_characteristic_14_chzn").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/#change-update-events

Indicentally, you're using jQuery, so

```
document.getElementById('hikashop_product_characteristic_19').value='35'
```

can simply be

```
$('#hikashop_product_characteristic_19').val('35');
```

This would all be better done with a single click event listener rather than inline onclick handlers.

```
$('img.hikashop_child_image').click(function() {
    ...
}
```

Comment: see my edit above, i think i just need to resolve a syntax error in my  JS, but not sure where.

Comment: Yeah, the idea wasn't to echo the script. Just use it in the page. And once, using your variables. Not once for every element.

Comment: oh yes i get what you are saying about once for every element. need to rethink this.